# include $_POST variables only if exists and send mail in PHP

Tags: php

i'm working on a small project in which i need to send email about incorrect information in a listing. so, i need to send only the incorrect data from form. All works fine but not receiving mail. Is there anything i did wrong.Please help...

```
   if(isset($_POST['report'])){
    $name = $_POST['business'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $phone =$_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $website = $_POST['website'];

    $toemail = "jafar.sain@gmail.com";
    $fromwebsite = "www.biz15.co.in";

    $error_listing = "business name";
    $error_listing_link = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

    $subject = "Biz15 - Report an Error in a Listing from ".$fromwebsite;
    $body = "You have been requested to go through the following errors from the listing - ".$error_listing."\n\n";
    $body .= "Listing Details:\n";
    $body .= "Listing Name - ".$error_listing."\n";
    $body .= "Listing Url - ".$error_listing_link."\n\n";
    $body .= "Error Details:\n";
    if($name){$body .= "Business Name - ".$name."\n";}
    if($address){$body .= "Address - ".$address."\n";}
    if($phone){$body .= "Phone Number - ".$phone."\n";}
    if($email){$body .= "Email - ".$email."\n";}
    if($website){$body .= "Website - ".$website."\n\n";}
    $body .= "---------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"."From: ".$toemail."\n"."Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
    if(@mail($toemail,$subject,$body,$headers)){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Success');</script>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Failed');</script>";
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you shouldnt surpress the error coming from `mail`.

Comment: whey you have used same email for To and From $toemail

Comment: Are you trying from the localhost? If yes, do you have a mail server set up?

Comment: What is your actual question? The title says it's about how to skip variables that aren't set when composing the mail. But th question itself says that the problem is that the mail isn't being delivered.

Comment: May i know are you getting success alert or Failed alert ?

Comment: May be @ character before mail function is making the condition true i think, please remove @ and check.

Comment: am not getting any alert message at all. It just reloads when i submit it.